# How do I force a child component to rerender when given new props values?

Tags: reactjs

I have tried this pattern.

```
ParentComponent
...
render(
return <ChildComponent newProps="newPropsValue />)

ChildComponent
...
ComponentWillReceiveProps{
this.setState({"propsKey": "newPropsValue"})
}
```

As far as I understand the initial component rendering is triggered by the props change, and as setState is asynchronous (for some reason), the rendering with the new state update is not done on the first pass.

However what I don't understand is why when it finally decides to update the state, it doesn't rerender the component. I thought state changes that are caused by setState always trigger a rerender.

So in the end I have a component that uselessly rerenders before the state is actually changed, and then does nothing when/if(?) the state is updated. I don't understand this behaviour at all.

Answer (score 0):

`setState` will trigger `componentUdpate` -> `componentWillUpdate` -> `render`. `props` change will trigger `componentWillReceiveProps` before this chain. You can have a look here at this image about [React lifecycle](https://res.cloudinary.com/hashnode/image/upload/v1458845434/necdybhogap8hp8fln1p.png). You can see the different how `React` behave on `props` and `state`.

So:

> However what I don't understand is why when it finally decides to update the state, it doesn't re-render the component.

Updating `state` by `setState` will trigger the `render` function (re-render).  And `props` also trigger `render` as well.

Following your code:

1. `componentWillReceiveProps`:

   - `this.props.newProps="newPropsValue"`
   - `this.state.propsKey="newPropsValue"`
2. `render`: as above, nothing change.
3. If any event of `childComponent` setting `propsKey` by `setState` (`onClick`, `onChange` ...). Assuming `setState({propsKey: "anotherValue"})`. Then `render` will be triggered again with `this.state.propsKey="anotherValue` and `this.props.newProps="newPropsValue"`

Now let's update your `childComponent`'s `props` within `parentComponent`, assuming `newProps="latestPropsValue"`:

1. Before `componentWillReceiveProps`:

   - `this.props.newProps="latestPropsValue"`
   - `this.state.propsKey="anotherValue"`
2. After `componentWillReceiveProps`:

   - `this.props.newProps="latestPropsValue"`
   - `this.state.propsKey="latestPropsValue"`

> How do I force a child component to rerender when given new props values?

If your `render` is using `state` then `setState` inside `render`. And if you are using `props` inside `render`, it also being updated accordingly

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Why doesn't state change trigger a 2nd cycle? And to repeat my question: **How do I force a child component to rerender when given new props values?**

Answer (score 0):

I have found a nice solution using **key** attribute. If we changed **key** property of a child component or some portion of React Component, it will re-render entirely. It will use when you need to re-render some portion of React Component or re-render a child component depending on props or state. Here is a example. I will re-render the full component.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { PrEditInput } from "./shared";

const BucketInput = ({ bucketPrice = [], handleBucketsUpdate, mood }) => {
  const data = Array.isArray(bucketPrice) ? bucketPrice : [];
  const [state, setState] = useState(Date.now());
  useEffect(() => {
    setState(Date.now());
  }, [mood, bucketPrice]);
  return (
    <span key={state}>
      {data.map((item) => (
        <PrEditInput
          key={item.id}
          label={item?.bucket?.name}
          name={item.bucketId}
          defaultValue={item.price}
          onChange={handleBucketsUpdate}
          mood={mood}
        />
      ))}
    </span>
  );
};

export default BucketInput;
```

Comment: This is correct and to my surprise React actually allows use of key prop outside lists! https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useState#resetting-state-with-a-key